# Java List/Recursion bug

Tags: java, recursion, quicksort

New to Java.  I'm following a book and an example is given on quicksort which works just fine.  I understand the algorithm but wanted to print the array before each recursion to really see what was going on with the lower and higher arrays.

I thought I'd just declare a separate list and populate it with the lower, pivot, and higher values but it seems to throw off all of the functionality.  The recursion seems to remain intact but it doesn't actually sort.  Therefore, it overflows and quits.

I'm almost certain there's a fundamental Java concept I'm missing here.

Everything but the lines wrapped in comments was taken from the book.  The lines between the commented lines are my own.

```
package quicksort;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class App {

    public static List<Integer> quicksort(List<Integer> numbers){
        if (numbers.size() < 2){
            return numbers;
        }

        final Integer pivot = numbers.get(0);
        final List<Integer> lower = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<Integer> higher = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.size(); i++){
            if (numbers.get(i) < pivot){
                lower.add(numbers.get(i));
            }
            else{
                    higher.add(numbers.get(i));
            }
        }

        // Makes things go all squirrrrrrrrely
        final List<Integer> notYetSorted = lower;
        notYetSorted.add(pivot);
        notYetSorted.addAll(higher);

        System.out.println("During: " + notYetSorted);
        // -------------

        final List<Integer> sorted = quicksort(lower);

        sorted.add(pivot);

        sorted.addAll(quicksort(higher));

        return sorted;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>();

        intList.add(5);
        intList.add(8);
        intList.add(2);
        intList.add(9);
        intList.add(10);
        intList.add(3);
        intList.add(4);
        intList.add(7);
        intList.add(1);
        intList.add(6);

        System.out.println("Before: " + intList);
        System.out.println("After: " + quicksort(intList).toString());
    }  

}
```

Comment: Please mention all the errors in the output. This gives a - `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError` Also, please put the steps in words.

Comment: Instead of individually adding each number to the list you can also do `intList.addAll(Arrays.asList(5,8,2,9,10,3,4,7,1,6));`

Comment: Borat - I'll keep this in mind going forward.  Thanks!
vandle - I was wondering if something like this was out there.  Thanks so much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is at the start of this block:

```
final List<Integer> notYetSorted = lower;
notYetSorted.add(pivot);
notYetSorted.addAll(higher);

System.out.println("During: " + notYetSorted);
// -------------

final List<Integer> sorted = quicksort(lower);
```

Unlike C++, Java does not perform a deep copy when you assign a new variable to an existing one.  So `notYetSorted` and `lower` actually refer to the exact same list in memory - any changes you then make to `notYetSorted` are also made to `lower`.

Thus, in the final line of that block, you are calling quicksort on a `List` of the same size you started with, all the time.  This is why it recurses forever.

Change the first line to:

```
final List<Integer> notYetSorted = new ArrayList<>(lower);
```

And all should be well.